# Bootstrap in Webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I just get a webpage design in which Bootstrap is used locally (that means - they downloaded the js file and used it).

Now, I'm building a React app where I want to use this design. Everything works ok, except I can't import Bootstrap to work properly.

How should I import Bootstrap to make my design responsive?